# Buck controller IC identification, SOT-23-6 package, top marking 22A0

Tags: identification, buck

[image: photo of PCB around unidentified IC]

I have a DC to DC buck converter.
Input: 10 V to 30 V DC
Output: 6 V, 2.5 A, 15 W LED load
External FET is used.

Switching controller IC SOT-23-6 package and marking on IC is 22A0.
I tried to search on Google with this information, but I am not finding the device.

Can you please help me to find out this IC part no or equivalent to this specification?

Comment: Could you please put a photo of the chip and the surrounding components, if possible?

Comment: Hi rohat,Photo added in post pls check